# Wordcloud error in Rmarkdown: only one wordcloud shows up in html

Tags: r, r-markdown, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I successfully created two wordclouds in Rmarkdown by importing two different datasets, but one wordcloud did not show up after I knit it to html. Does anyone know how to fix it?

---

### output: html_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(here)
library(rio)
```

### WordCloud 1

```
s1 <- import(here("data", "set1.xlsx"))
wordcloud2(s1, color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "dark")
```

### WordCloud 2

```
s2 <- import(here("data", "set2.xlsx"))
wordcloud2(s2, color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "dark")
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without the data

Comment: Could you privide a reproducible example with sample data?

Comment: @awchisholm Thank you for pointing this out. I have created an example repo at https://github.com/hshung/WordCloud_trial.git

Comment: Please provide a minimal self contained example. You will be more likely to get an answer if the work to reproduce the issue does not require cloning external git repositories or manually downloading data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully reproducible working example that writes the results to image files then views them. I used `dput(head(s1))` to get the example data. Comment out for your environment.

````
---
title: "WordCloud_Trial"
output: html_document
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(wordcloud2)
library(here)
library(rio)
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)
```

## WordCloud 1
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, include=F}
#s1 <- import(here("data", "set1.xlsx"))
s1 <- structure(list(Type = c("provide", "include", "develop", "support", 
"create", "suggest"), `Token Frequency` = c(1218, 1095, 1088, 
1078, 1005, 988)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
w1 <- wordcloud2(s1, color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "dark")
saveWidget(w1, '1.html', selfcontained = F)
webshot('1.html', '1.png', vwidth=700,vheight=500, delay = 5)
```
![](1.png)

## WordCloud 2
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, include=F}
#s2 <- import(here("data", "set2.xlsx")) 
s2 <- structure(list(Type = c("decrease", "cope", "accommodate", "confirm", 
"reinforce", "advance"), `Token Frequency` = c(251, 240, 232, 
229, 228, 227)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
w2 = wordcloud2(s2, color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "dark")
saveWidget(w2, '2.html', selfcontained = F)
webshot('2.html', '2.png', vwidth=700,vheight=500, delay = 5)
```
![](2.png)
````

Comment: I appreciate your help! I tried to reproduce the data, but the results did't produce any image files. It showed no image at path for ![](1.png) and ![](2.png). @awchisholm

Comment: Did you install the webshot and htmlwidgets packages?